# BigQuery UDF to remove accents/diacritics in a string

Tags: google-bigquery, bigquery-udf, unaccent

Using this javascript code we can remove accents/diacritics in a string.

```
var originalText = "éàçèñ"
var result = originalText.normalize('NFD').replace(/[\u0300-\u036f]/g, "")
console.log(result) // eacen
```

If we create a BigQuery UDF it does not (even with double \).

```
 CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION project.remove_accent(x STRING)
RETURNS STRING
  LANGUAGE js AS """
  return x.normalize("NFD").replace(/[\u0300-\u036f]/g, "");
""";

SELECT project.remove_accent("éàçèñ") --"éàçèñ"
```

Any thoughts on that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider below approach

```
select originalText, 
  regexp_replace(normalize(originalText, NFD), r"\pM", '') output
```

if applied to sample data in your question - output is

[image]

You can easily wrap it with SQL UDF if you wish